# Update multiple MySql rows if Value exists

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a mysql database from a list that is submitted from a textarea. Every line in the textarea represents a value that is to be compared to existing entries in the database. If there is a match than the Status in that row has to be updated. With this Code only the last line from the textarea has an effect. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['regnr']))
{
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "root";
$db_name = "sonstwas";
$port = 3306;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$new_status = 2;
$lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $_POST["regnr"]);

foreach ($lines as $key => $value){
    $sql = "UPDATE kunden ". "SET Status = $new_status ". "WHERE RegNr = '$value'";
    //echo 'rows '.$key.' ist: "'.$value.'"<br>';
    }


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
else
{
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<textarea name="regnr" rows="30" id="regnr"></textarea>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</form>

 <?php
         }
      ?>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping and preparing sql-statements, but you're not doing anything with that (except of course with the last prepared statement).
So move the execution of the sql statements inside the loop.

```
foreach ($lines as $key => $value){
    $sql = "UPDATE kunden ". "SET Status = $new_status ". "WHERE RegNr = '$value'";
    //echo 'rows '.$key.' ist: "'.$value.'"<br>';
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: Ask yourself what will happen if I write in your textarea something like this: "; DELETE FROM kunden"

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. I was sitting on that for hours. Yet the solution is so simple.